# JANUS GridEX: how to sort some column by values for different column C#

Tags: c#, winforms, janus, gridex

I need to sort column that the value is string that show date.
and if I sort it by click on th head of thw column it's not work good.
So, I want that when click on the head of the column to sort - it sort the column by different values from different column.

like:

column: `dateDescription`
column: `date`

I want that when click on head of column `dateDescription` it sort by the value in column `date` and not by the default: `dateDescription`

I try to write in the code like:

```
private void M_MortagagePaymentGrid_ColumnHeaderClick(object sender, Janus.Windows.GridEX.ColumnActionEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column.Index == 4)// this column: dateDescription 
    {
      //hear I want to sort by the values of the column date
      // what to write hear??
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know specifically for Janus.GridEx but you should probably just call the base ColumnHeaderClick event with the changed Eventargument. Check the Janus documentation to get to the name of the base function you need to call.
Example code given below.

```
private void M_MortagagePaymentGrid_ColumnHeaderClick(object sender, Janus.Windows.GridEX.ColumnActionEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column.Index == 4)// this column: dateDescription 
    {
        e.Column.Index = 3; //use the column index for the date column
    }
    //Call the base Event handler here with (sender, e)

}
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Nothing happened